# Using SED to delete a line that has multiple fields to match

Tags: sed

I have a file that has 12 columns of data.  I would like to delete / remove the entire line if column 5 equals "A" and column 12 equals "Z".  Is this possible using SED?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the data? How are the "columns" defined?

Comment: Are you asking for sed only, or using the unix tools in general?

Answer (score 3):

You can. Suppose your columns are separated by spaces:

```
sed -i -e '/\([^ ]* *\)\{4\}A *\([^ ]* *\)\{6\}Z/d' file
```

The `-i` flag is used to edit the file in place.

The pattern `[^ ]* *` matches zero or more (indicated by the asterisk) characters that aren't spaces (indicated by the space character after the `^` in the brackets) followed by zero or more spaces.

Placing this pattern between backslashed parenthesis, we can group it into a single expression, and we can then use backslashed braces to repeat the expression. Four times initially, then match an `A` followed by spaces, then the pattern again repeated six times, then the `Z`.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `sed`, but it is much easier with `awk`:

```
awk '! ( $5 == "A" && $12 == "Z" )' input-file
```

or

```
awk '$5 != "A" || $12 != "Z"' input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F -ane 'print unless($F[4] eq "A" and $F[11] eq "Z") your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
1 2 3 4 A 6 7 8 9 10 11 Z
> perl -F -ane 'print unless($F[4] eq "A" and $F[11] eq "Z")' temp
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
>
```